Can I send my recorded frontend video to backend and store it in a particular folder where I want?
I am using Flask, in which I have written html files under templates folder. Within it I have a html file in which I have implemented the screen recording.
The problem is that I can download the video directly after it has been recorded. But actually I want it to get saved in a folder called recordings which is under my Flask project...
Any help would be greatly appreciated
startRecording function--
function startRecording() {
navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({ video: true }).then(stream => {
mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = event => recordedChunks.push(event.data);
mediaRecorder.start();
startRecordingButton.disabled = true;
stopRecordingButton.disabled = false;
}).catch(error => {
console.error('Error starting recording:', error);
});
}
stopRecording function--
function stopRecording() {
if (mediaRecorder && mediaRecorder.state !== 'inactive') {
mediaRecorder.stop();
startRecordingButton.disabled = false;
stopRecordingButton.disabled = true;
if (confirm('Do you want to save the recording?')) {
saveRecording();
}
}
}


If you want to upload a video recording to the server and save it within a folder, you can do it using the Fetch API. To do this, convert the video data into a Blob and add it to a FormData object. This is then uploaded to the server in the background via POST request.
Within the endpoint you can request the file from the dict request.files using the key used to add it to the form. You will receive an object of type FileStorage, which you can save in a suitable location. In the following example, a subdirectory in the instance folder is used for this purpose.
from flask import (
    Flask, 
    abort, 
    render_template, 
    request
)
from mimetypes import guess_extension
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_mapping(
    UPLOAD_FOLDER = os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'recordings')
)
os.makedirs(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], exist_ok=True)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.post('/upload')
def upload():
    if file := request.files.get('video'):
        extname = guess_extension(file.mimetype)
        if not extname:
            abort(400)

        # Check for allowed file extensions.

        i = 1
        while True:
            dst = os.path.join(
                app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],
                secure_filename(f'video_{i}{extname}')
            )
            if not os.path.exists(dst): break
            i += 1

        file.save(dst)

        return ''
    abort(400)

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <button id="rec-btn">Start / Stop</button>
    </main>

    <script>
        (function() {
            const recBtn = document.getElementById('rec-btn');

            const startRecording = () => {
                let recorder; 

                const stopRecording = () => {
                    recorder && recorder.stop();
                };

                const constraints = { video: true };
                navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(constraints)
                    .then(stream => {
                        let chunks = []
                        recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
                        recorder.ondataavailable = event => {
                            chunks.push(event.data);
                        };
                        recorder.onstart = event => {
                            console.log('Recording started.');
                        };
                        recorder.onstop = event => {
                            console.log('Recording stopped.')

                            let blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: recorder.mimeType }); 
                            chunks = [];

                            if (confirm('Do you want to save the recording?')) {
                                const formData = new FormData();
                                formData.append('video', blob);

                                fetch('/upload', {
                                    method: 'POST',
                                    cache: 'no-cache',
                                    body: formData
                                }).then(resp => {
                                    if (!resp.ok) {
                                        throw new Error('Upload failed.');
                                    }
                                }).catch(console.error);
                            }

                            recBtn.removeEventListener('click', stopRecording);
                            recBtn.addEventListener('click', startRecording);
                        };

                        recBtn.removeEventListener('click', startRecording);
                        recBtn.addEventListener('click', stopRecording);
                        recorder.start();
                    })
                    .catch(console.error);
            };

            if (!navigator.mediaDevices) {
                console.error('MediaDevices not supported.')
                recBtn.remove();
                return;
            }

            recBtn.addEventListener('click', startRecording);
        })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>

